# Draw circle to tha location i clicked doesn't work

Tags: java

i modified the code
and the same output  no circle when i click the mouse

```
                  public   class gui extends JFrame{
              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                private final JPanel mousepanal;
                        private final JLabel stutespar ;



           int x=0;
            int y=0;



                  public gui() {
                     super("title");
                       mousepanal = new JPanel();

                       mousepanal.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                       add(mousepanal,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                     add(edffnmlsdfkj,BorderLayout.WEST);
                       stutespar = new JLabel();
                       add(stutespar,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                       Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
                      Paintcir p = new Paintcir();
                       mousepanal.addMouseListener(handler);
                       mousepanal.addMouseMotionListener(handler);


                  }
```

///////////////////////////

```
        private class Handlerclass extends JPanel implements                     MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        stutespar.setText(String.format("clicked at %d %d",e.getX(),e.getY()));


           x=e.getX();
           y=e.getY();
```

how to call repaint()?

```
  repaint();

    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
     stutespar.setText("you bress mouse");


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

         stutespar.setText("mouse realse");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      stutespar.setText("you entered the mouse");
   //   mousepanal.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      stutespar.setText("exsitd");
    //  mousepanal.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        stutespar.setText("dragged");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        stutespar.setText("moved");
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

```
                          @Override
                          public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                     super.paintComponents(g);
                  this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                    g.setColor(Color.green);

           g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
       //     g.fillOval(x+50, y+100, 40, 40);
              }





                 }
              }
```

this is the main class

```
                public   class Main extends JFrame {
                public static void main(String[] args) {

                gui g = new gui();
              g.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                  g.setSize(500,500);
                    g.setVisible(true);





                       }   
                 }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give any errors? What are you expecting exactly as output?

Comment: The output out is i create the frame 
When i click ..
Nothing happens

Comment: x=e.getX();
y=e.getY();
x and y aren't being used just saying

Comment: Try to putting Graphics g global

Comment: g.drawOval(x,y, 20, 20);

i put it global 
when click in the frame it gives me error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Some problems:

1. You should use `super.paintComponent(...)` without the "s".
2. However, in this case it doesn't matter because JFrame doesn't have a paintComponent() method. You should always use the `@Override` before the method to make sure you are actually overriding a method of the class.

When you do custom painting:

1. you override the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and add the panel to a frame.
2. The MouseListener should be defined in your custom panel class.
3. on the mouse event you need to invoke repaint() so the component can repaint itself

Comment: I did and I gave you some suggestions. The code hasn't changed in the last 3 days so there is nothing else to check. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that uses the suggestions given.